# Does jOOQ support PostgreSQL's C style escape strings?

Tags: postgresql, jooq

Are PostgreSQL's C style escape strings supported in jOOQ?

I have query where I'm paginating (limit & offset style) and returning the total count by parsing the output of EXPLAIN, one of the recommended ways to get a quick count estimate by the PostgreSQL wiki (
https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Count_estimate). When I initially implemented this function I escaped the function using PG's C style escapes (section 4.1.2.2 of https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html). The following is a valid query according to PG however when trying to render it in jOOQ `Tools#renderAndBind(Context<?>, String, List<QueryPart>)` throws an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` as it picks up the double quote in the search term as the start of an identifier and runs off the end of the array looking for the other one.

```
select 
  (
    select count_estimate(E'select 1
    from "public"."foo"
    where (
        "public"."foo"."name" = \'"\'
    )')
  ) as "total", 
  (
    select array_to_json(coalesce(
      array_agg("alias_95585617"."data" order by 
        "alias_95585617"."name" asc nulls last
      ), 
      cast('{}' as jsonb[])
    ))
    from (
      select
          "public"."foo"."name",
          row(
              "public"."foo"."id",
              "public"."foo"."name"
          ) as "data"
      from "public"."foo"
      where (
        "public"."foo"."name" = '"'
      )
      order by 
        "public"."foo"."name" asc nulls last
      limit 30
      offset 120
    ) as "alias_95585617"
  ) as "data"
```

Reimplementing this function in jOOQ using double dollar quoting works as expected. I was going to submit this as a bug but I thought I would check that this is a feature of PG that jOOQ intends to support first.

Using (Oracle JDK 1.8.0_144, jOOQ 3.8.3, PG 9.5.5, PGJDBC 42.1.4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this isn't supported in jOOQ 3.10 yet. But it certainly makes sense. I've added an issue to the roadmap: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/6704